# call_user_func(array(self, 'method')) - do I have to name the class?

Tags: php, oop

In PHP, `call_user_func(array(self, 'method_name'))` doesn't work. The `self` keyword cannot be used in that context. I need to actually include the name of the class `call_user_func(array('class_name', 'method_name'))`.

However, if I'm not in a static function, the `$this` variable does work in that context. Why the difference?

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the name of the current class context, use get_class() (without any parameters) or __CLASS__.

You've already written the difference; self is a keyword, and is not usable as a reference in an array (what kind of type should that be in PHP?). get_class() returns a string, and the array()-callback supports using a string as the first name to do a static call.

Comment: Thanks. I'd forgotten about `__CLASS__`.

Comment: Note: `self` is not a keyword in that context. And it's a string then.

Comment: If you need PHP late static binding, you have to use `get_called_class()` instead of `__CLASS__` here.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `__CLASS__` to get the class name. Also it *may* work to use `call_user_func('self::method_name')` directly, but I didn't test it and the [documentation about callbacks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: As `array(self, 'method_name')` is not working, the same callback `'self::method_name'` won't work either, both are identical. The difference is only that the one is using an array and the other the string.

Comment: @harke Another difference would be that one contains `self` in a string and the other uses it as a keyword.

Comment: @Adrian Lang: It didn't on my one PHP 5.3 box, but it [does here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YNzKLS). @Alin Purcaru: No, `self` is an undefined constant (not a keyword) and it evaluates to string `'self'`. See the [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YNzKLS), it makes that behavior visible.

Comment: @hakre :) Self is not an "undefined constant". There's no such thing. PHP won't recognise `self` as a keyword in that context and tries for the next available thing, a constant with the name "self", when it doesn't find that constant it throws a notice, but falls back to the string "self".

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: If we can agree that a keyword is (potentially) an undefined constant which always will be evaluated as string, we actually mean the same, right :)

Comment: @hakre But we won't agree on that. Keywords are not constants. And I would have expected PHP to give you an error (or at least a warning) for using self like that. Just try it with `static` to understand what I mean. Maybe there are some implementation problems with `self`.

Comment: @Alinn Purcaru: Well I can agree on that. If the parser finds a keyword and tries to resolve it to a constant as last resort and then decides it's an undefined one (as you lined it up), that perfectly makes sense. I was a bit nit-picking that a constant is not a keyword, which was a too narrowed view of mine probably. And `static` is different to `self`, so I don't think it's possible to use `static` to explain this behavior of `self`.

Answer (score 3):

`self` is just an undefined constant, so it expresses `'self'`. So these two are the same:

```
array(self, 'method_name');
array('self', 'method_name');
```

And depending on the PHP version you use, this actually works, see [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YNzKLS).

In case it does not work with your PHP version, some alternatives are:

```
call_user_func(array(__CLASS__, 'method_name'));
```

or

```
call_user_func(__CLASS__.'::method_name'));
```

or (in case you don't need `call_user_func`):

```
self::method_name();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP 5.5, you can do `[self::class, 'methodName']`.

`::class` is really useful for situations where you have a class name (maybe a local alias) and you need to generate the full class name as a string.

Comment: Neat. I hadn't come across that.

Comment: Upvoted as I thought to add myself before seeing this. Documented under https://php.net/oop5.constants (above [linkable example](https://php.net/oop5.constants#example-187)).

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5.3, you can write `call_user_func('self::method')` or `call_user_func(array('self', 'method'))`. I suppose the latter could work in older versions as well.